# unable to use for_each and count in terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, terraform-provider-azure

I have .tfvars file below with below contents as the the input variables

```
aks_configuration = {
  aks1 = {
    name                   = "cnitest"
    location               = "westeurope"
    kubernetes_version = "1.22.4"
    dns_prefix             = "cnitest"
    default_nodepool_name  = "general"
    default_nodepool_size  = "Standard_B2s"
    default_nodepool_count = 2
    default_node_pool_autoscale = true
    default_node_pool_autoscale_min_count = 1
    default_node_pool_autoscale_max_count = 2
    aks_zones = null
    network_plugin = null
    network_policy = null
    vnet_name = null
    vnet_enabled = false
    subnet_name = null
    objectID= ["*********]

    nodepool = [
      {
        name                = "dts"
        vm_size             = "Standard_B2s"
        enable_auto_scaling = true
        mode                = "user"
        node_count          = 1
        max_count           = 2
        min_count           = 1

      }
    ]

  }

}
```

Now I need to create an aks cluster with conditions to choose azurecni or kubenet as the part of the network configuration.

if the vnet_enabled is false it should disable data resource in the terraform and give the value as null for the below configuration

```
#get nodepool vnet subnet ID

data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
    for_each            = local.aks_config.vnet_enabled

  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg-name
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  for_each            = local.aks_config
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg-name
  dns_prefix          = each.value.dns_prefix
  default_node_pool {
    name                = each.value.default_nodepool_name
    node_count          = each.value.default_nodepool_count
    vm_size             = each.value.default_nodepool_size
    enable_auto_scaling = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale
    min_count           = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale_min_count
    max_count           = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale_max_count
    vnet_subnet_id =  data.azurerm_subnet.example[each.key].id
    zones = each.value.aks_zones
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = each.value.network_plugin
    network_policy = each.value.network_policy
  }
  # azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
  #   managed = true
  #   admin_group_object_ids = [each.value.objectID]
  # }
}
```

Comment: Your cod does not use `aks_configuration` at all. Also what's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

If the vnet integration needs to be done which is the parameter `vnet_enabled` is set to true then the data block fetches the details of subnet to be used by the AKS Cluster and then uses it and also sets the network plugin to `azure` . If its false then the data block is not utilized and the subnet is provided null value in AKS cluster and it uses `kubenet. You don't need to add ***network plugin*** and ***network policy*** in the locals , you can leverage the same in the conditional values.

To achieve the above , You have to use something like below :

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
    for_each            = local.aks_configuration.vnet_enabled ? 1 : 0

  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.rg-name
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  for_each            = local.aks_configuration
  name                = each.value.name
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = var.rg-name
  dns_prefix          = each.value.dns_prefix
  default_node_pool {
    name                = each.value.default_nodepool_name
    node_count          = each.value.default_nodepool_count
    vm_size             = each.value.default_nodepool_size
    enable_auto_scaling = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale
    min_count           = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale_min_count
    max_count           = each.value.default_node_pool_autoscale_max_count
    vnet_subnet_id =  each.value.vnet_enabled ? data.azurerm_subnet.example[0].id : null
    zones = each.value.aks_zones
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  network_profile {
    network_plugin = each.value.vnet_enabled ? "azure" : "kubenet"
    network_policy = each.value.vnet_enabled ? "azure" : "calico"
  }
  # azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
  #   managed = true
  #   admin_group_object_ids = [each.value.objectID]
  # }
}
```